# How to take screenshot on Fail, with htmlunitdriver in java?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, selenium3, screenshot, headless

I am running Selenium along with cucumber with java, and trying to Capture screenshot on fail with htmlunitdriver in java?

Can you help me how to capture a screenshot with HTMLunitDriver. I tried phantomjs but unfortunately phantom has no function like browserVersion in HtmlUnitDrive. that is why we have to stay with HTMLUNITDRIVER.

Answer (score 1):

HtmlUnit does not have screenshot function, as the page is not rendered.

Here is the feedback from the developers on a similar question:

> HtmlUnit is a headless browser, and makes no attempt to render
>   content. This is the reason that the HtmlUnitDriver does not support
>   the TakesScreenshot interface.
>
> If you need to take screenshots, then I'd suggest using something like
>   the FirefoxDriver.
>
> Marking as "WontFix" as this is the expected behaviour.
>
> https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/1361

The thread notes that someone made some code to throw all the html,css,images etc into a zip for analyses or manual rendering in a real browser. Have a look at this HtmlUnit extentions here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/selenium-developers/PTR_j4xLVRM/k2yVq01Fa7oJ